# jQuery .index(), confusing changes with argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/understanding-index/

Perhaps I missed something in the article above, but I'm having some trouble understanding *why* the index number changes the way it does when an argument is used with .index().

For instance, with

```
<body> 
        <button id="console2">consoleSection2</button>
        <ul>
            <div class="test"></div>
            <li id="foo2">foo</li>
            <li id="bar2" class="test">bar</li>
            <li id="baz2">baz</li>
            <div class="test"></div>
        </ul>
        <div id="last"></div>
</body>
```

if I run

```
console.log( 
    "Index: " + $("#foo2").index()
);
```

I get *"Index: 1"*, whereas if I run

"Index: " + $("#foo2").index("li")

I get *"Index: 0"*.

Why does it change? To me, it would stay the same since "#foo2" is already in an "li" element.

Plus, why would it go to 0 as an Index? Is that because it's the first instance of "li" with an id of "#foo2"?

http://jsfiddle.net/f88zxaxo/

Comment: That is invalid html. Divs should not be siblings of a UL. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html

Comment: It's not a final product, just stuff I'm testing with/learning. Plus it's similar to http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/understanding-index/ . But thanks for the info anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a selector string into `.index()`, the return value indicates the location of the first matching element *within the list of elements comprising the jQuery object.*

Without an argument, `.index()` tells you the position of your element *within its HTML container element among its siblings.*

You get 1 back from `$("#foo2").index()` because the "foo2" element is at position 1 in the elements descended from the containing `<ul>` (and that's invalid markup, by the way).  However, you get back 0 from `$("#foo2").index("li")` because the jQuery object has only one element in it, and it's an `<li>` element. If you tried `$("#foo2").index("span")`, you'd get -1 back.

Comment: Can you give me an example of having more than one element in the jQuery object? I have two instances of "div" with a class of "test", but logging "Index: " + $(".test").index("div") also turns up "Index: 0".

Comment: @Terf consider `$("li")` for your document. That jQuery object will have 3 elements in it. Thus, `$("li").index("#baz2")` will be 2, while `$("#baz2").index()` will be 3 and `$("#baz2").index("li")` will again be 0.

Comment: @Terf think of it like this: with no arguments, `.index()` lets you ask about the position of the first matched element in relation to the structure of the DOM. *With* an argument, `.index()` lets you ask about the collection of selected elements in the jQuery object and has nothing to do with the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I have a better understanding now.